# CS:GO Error - Auto-Disconnect problem (Custom servers only)

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I can play in "official" servers without any issue (like competitive match/casual etc).
but when I go into a custom server, after few seconds it shows this error:
"Warning: Connection problem, Auto-disconnect in: 00:25 seconds".
[image]

I tried to verify files, reinstall game.. it didn't fix.

Comment: Are you on WIFI? And does the same error appear on wired connections too?

Comment: @dly I am not on WIFI, using wired connection.
I cannot try with WIFI (PC).

Answer (score 1):

This is what Steam says about this issue:

> Exit Steam.
>
> Please open Internet Explorer, Safari or Firefox and type
> `steam://flushconfig` then press Enter. (If asked to allow this website
> to open a program, please click 'Allow' or 'OK')
>
> When prompted by Steam to reset your configuration, please click 'OK'
> to confirm.
>
> Once done, login to Steam and re-test the issue.
>
> **If you have multiple installation folders for games doing this process
> will remove them. You will need to add the folders again in Steam so
> that your games will appear as installed.**
>
> In order to add the folders please do the following:
>
> 1. Open Steam
> 2. Click Steam > Settings (Preferences on Mac)
> 3. Navigate to the 'Downloads' tab
> 4. Click the 'Steam Library Folders' button
> 5. Click on 'Add Library Folder' and add the directory that contains your games
> 6. Click 'OK'
> 7. Restart Steam

If the issue persists, make sure your network is optimized for Steam. Check the [network troubleshooting](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/669A-2F68-D1D1-A5EC) support page, especially the [ports section](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/2EA8-4D75-DA21-31EB). Also some ISPs have trouble with Steam:

- 012.net (Steam traffic blocked)
- Bluewin (Firewall blocks Steam from provider side - must be disabled through provider's service portal)
- Dutch Telecom (Steam traffic blocked)
- ISPFree (Steam traffic blocked)
- Micronet Broadband (Steam traffic blocked)